# Making a sprite jump in AndEngine using pshysics box 2d

Tags: android, andengine

I have a sprite, how do I make it jump using the *andEngine* extension `PhsycicsBox2D`?

**currently**, I have done everything but it doesn't jump.

**OnTouch** to let it jump

```
        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,
                TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
            {

                b.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(b.getLinearVelocity().x, -13.5f)); 


            }
            return false;
        }
```

**The player, physics world, body, and the connector.**

```
        player = new AnimatedSprite(playerX, playerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

            physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
            mScene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);

            final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            b = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, player, BodyType.StaticBody, objectFixtureDef);

            physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(player, b, true, true));

            mScene.attachChild(player);
```

Comment: Hoping my answer may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to update sprites position every time in your update Handler as follows: get all bodies in world Now get position of body then update sprite position

```
mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new Timer(1f, new ITimerCallback() {



                        @Override
                        public void onTick() {

                                Iterator<Body> it = bxWorld.getBodies();`
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                            Body b = it.next();
                            Object userData = b.getUserData();

                            if (userData != null && userData instanceof Sprite) {
                                //Synchronize the Sprites position and rotation with the corresponding body
                                final Sprite sprite = (Sprite)userData;
                                final Vector2 pos = b.getPosition();
                                sprite.setPosition(pos.x * PTM_RATIO, pos.y * PTM_RATIO);
                                sprite.setRotation(-1.0f * ccMacros.CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b.getAngle()));

                            }   
                        }
                        }

                }));
```

If you want to check for bodies visibility, use debug draw class.

Comment: it is physics world.You have to place in update Handler.So that it update the sprite as the body updates its position.

Comment: currently I get errors form PTM_RATIO, and ccMacros

Comment: PTM_RATIO = 32; and   sprite.setRotation(0));

Comment: Never mind, I gave up that idea. Thank you. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Pathmodifire

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PathModifierExample.java?r=4f9e33fa42af65ad61057787d03f2c08fc551b62

Pathmodifire will do the trick

pass the coordinate of current position to next position (Jump position)

Comment: Im looking to use the physicsbox2d extension, If i douldn't find an answer to my problem I will look at your method.